# wide color on iPhone7

Tags: ios, cgcontextref

The Question is :

When working on iPhone7,

I get `CGContextRef` from `UIView`, then the *bitsPerPixel* is *64*. Cause my **.a** can only work with traditional RGB colorspace bitmap buffer whose bitsPerPixel is 32,

Could someone know how to convert `CGContextRef` whose colorspace is wide color to `tranditional CGContextRef` just like on iPhone6 ?

Comment: This is just an idea. Okay, so wide color is a trait (UIDisplayGamut). So perhaps you could use a custom container view controller so that you could call `setOverrideTraitCollection(_:forChildViewController:)` and fool your child view controller into believing it's running on a device without wide color.

Comment: @matt Thanks a lot for anwser, I'll have a try. Yesterday, I find a way to deal with wide color, set the UIView's layer property "contentsFormat" to kCAContentsFormatRGBA8Uint, then the CGContextRef got from runtime is 32 bitsPerPixel

Comment: If that works, you should post it as an answer! This wide color stuff is certainly going to cause some confusion, so your work here could be very useful to others. (Also please note that I don't know whether my idea will work! I need you to try it for me.)

Comment: @matt I've tried your idea, but it seems failed. But the way I found just work fine.

Comment: That is great. Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is below:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_9_3
-(void) layerWillDraw:(CALayer *)layer 
{
    if( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10.0 )
    {
        NSString* format = layer.contentsFormat;
        if( ![format isEqualToString:kCAContentsFormatRGBA8Uint]  )
            layer.contentsFormat = kCAContentsFormatRGBA8Uint;
    }
}
#endif
```

add the code above to the view which you will draw on, then the CGContextRef got from the view is traditional, just as on iPhone6